# A jquery event that fires on the form when saving completes with :remote => true form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a success/failure event when a form with :remote => true has been saved.

I've tried:

```
$( '#feedback-form' ).bind( 'ajaxSuccess', function( data, status, xhr ) { 
   alert( 'success' ); 
} )
```

But that fires on #feedback-form for all successful ajax events, even if they completely unrelated to the ajax save of the form.

I understand why (ajaxSuccess is not specific to the form but to ajax), but I can't seem to find a :remote compatible equivalent to .submit() which fires when the ajax save is complete or has failed.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some specific binding from Jquery-ujs library. All is explain in documentation :

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

So you can bind only the `ajax:success` event

Comment: Thank you - that looks exactly like what I need.